# Automatically redirecting for multi tag link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, hyperlinks

I used to use this link: [C++ or C++11 or OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B%20or%20c%2B%2B11%20or%20opencv) to find the newest questions in tags I am interested in. It is now (**occasionally**)  redirects me directly to this: [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B).

Why does this happen?

**Edit:**

Yesterday, it was always redirecting the whole day. Today, It does not happen all the times.

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally clicking [tag:c++] _occasionally_?

Comment: No I see how the links changed in the browser I even tried to catch it before it changed.

Comment: *"I even tried to catch it before it changed"* Browser: \*reading stackoverflow.com\* NO!

Comment: Are you sure you were logged in during that time? Not logged-in users are not allowed to run multi-tag queries, and are redirected to the first tag.

Comment: @m0sa that it is.. I remembered that I tried to ask a this question and I figured that I am not logged in while the problem was occurring. Probably that is the problem

Comment: Yes I rembered now. I tried to copy the link before it redirect and then wen to the meta and figured that I am logged in. I did not notice that it may make difference